# How can I pass data from MainActivity to host Fragment data in bottomnavigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have bottom navigation in main Activity and  have a data in `MainActivity` and I want to pass that to HostFragments  I am using NavigationExtensions form google NavigationAndvancedSample sample
here the extension function I am using in MainActivity but do you know how I can pass data which is the best way to pass data which intent contains to HostFragments? You can see I have fragmentTag and navigationHostFragment

`````
fun BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navGraphIds: List<Int>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,containerId: Int,intent: Intent)



private fun obtainNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    fragmentTag: String,
    navGraphId: Int,
    containerId: Int
): NavHostFragment {
  // If the Nav Host fragment exists, return it
  val existingFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) as NavHostFragment?
  existingFragment?.let { return it }

  // Otherwise, create it and return it.
  val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.create(navGraphId)
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      .add(containerId, navHostFragment, fragmentTag)
      .commitNow()
  return navHostFragment
}````
`````

Comment: Could you describe the context on what data you want to pass from MainActivity more? Because it may be that the data flow should be redesigned so that parent activity won't communicate with fragments

Comment: You can use RxBus, take a look https://android.jlelse.eu/rxbus-kotlin-listen-where-ever-you-want-e6fc0760a4a8

Comment: Why you are downvoting my question? and refereng to a doc `Also You can access activity data from fragment:` which I have downvoted for a while ago because it make tighted couple between activity and fragment and my case is not simple Activity and Fragment ,I am talking about jetpack bottomnavigation .where I am working NavHostFragment

Answer (score 1):

Pass data using below code

```
Fragment fragment = findFragmentById(R.id.activity_content_4_fregment);
if (fragment instanceof Fragment_Class) {
    ((Fragment_Class) fragment).passdata(data);
}
```